# Why should a parent NSManagedObjectContext be of main queue concurrency type?

Tags: ios, core-data

I've read some articles talking about parent/child NSManagedObjectContext design, and most of them suggesting that a main queue concurrency type context should be the parent. In my understanding, the parent context should be the one that actually commits all changes to the persistent store, which may lead to a bunch of I/O operations and make UI unresponsive. So why do we need this design and how can we solve this problem?

Comment: I can recommend this blog post from Marcus Zarra [My Core Data Stack](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/). He discusses this design pattern. Marcus has written a few books on CoreData so knows his stuff.